# Scanalyze install

Tags: compiling, gcc, install-from-source

I am trying to install [Scanalyze](http://graphics.stanford.edu/software/scanalyze/#Distribution).

I downloaded the source code, and in the compilation instructions for Ubuntu, he has mentioned that for later versions of gcc (mine is 4+), there is a separate patched source, and the link for download is provided.

I used that link to download my source, and while I tried to compile using `make` I got the following error

```
    cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fwritable-strings’
```

Could you please help me how to overcome this and what changes I should make to install this efficiently? I am using Ubuntu 11.10.

This is the complete display after the `make`.

```
    make -j 1      scanalyze.debug BUILD=debug \
    --directory=OBJS/debug --makefile=../../Makefile -I../.. SKIPCVS=1
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/siddarth/scanalyze-1.0.3/OBJS/debug'
    g++ -fno-for-scope -fpermissive -fwritable-strings -w -g -I../.. -  
    I../../auxlibs/include/tnt -march=i686 -MMD -o plvMain.o -c ../../plvMain.cc
    cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fwritable-strings’
    make[1]: *** [plvMain.o] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/siddarth/scanalyze-1.0.3/OBJS/debug'
    make: *** [debug] Error 2
```

Comment: @Jai Not yet. It'll be EoL'd next month.

Comment: Is that the only error you got? Did you follow [these](http://graphics.stanford.edu/software/scanalyze/scanalyze-faq.html#Q2) instructions?

Comment: @EricCarvalho : Yes. That is the only error I got. Thanks for your reply. I saw the steps and I feel the first one would be more related to my problem. Please see the esit. I have included the output of the compilation. Please tell me if it is related. Am sry, but am new to linux.

Comment: @EricCarvalho : May I know wat is EOL? Just wanted to know.

Comment: End of Life. Non-LTS versions, like 11.10, are supported for 18 months. Ubuntu 11.10 was released oct-2011 and will be supported until apr-2013.

Comment: So, should I upgrade asap? @EricCarvalho

Comment: No need to hurry. You can wait for next month's 13.04 release. About the compilation problem, I really can't help, but this kind of thing is completely expected when you're dealing with old unsupported software. I suggest you try to find a newer alternative.

Comment: I am also having this problem. What was the fix?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the "-fwritable-strings" in file "Makedefs.Linux"

the next problem will be "pnt3.h" :) .. please keep asking

I'm try to build scanalyze too.

Comment: It seems like this is intended as an answer but that's not totally clear. Are you saying that removing `-fwritable-atrings` from `Makedefs.Linux` will fix the problem?